# laravel 9.0 Eloquent all() method doesn't return relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables Department and InspectionSite.

Department Migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('department_name', 100);
        });
    }
```

InspectionSite Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('inspection_sites', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('site_title');
            $table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Department::class);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Department Model:

```
class Department extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
  
    protected $fillable = ['depatment_name'];

    public function sites() {
        return $this->hasMany(InspectionSite::class);
    }

}
```

InspectionSite Model

```
class InspectionSite extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function department() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class, 'department_id');
    }
}
```

getting data from controller

```
 public function get() {
        $selector = ['site_title AS title', 'site_type' ];
        $sites = InspectionSite::all();
        return response()->json($sites->department, 200);
    }
```

when I call find() method it returns relationship data but not in all() method?

```
public function get() {
    $departments = Department::all();
    return response()->json($departments->sites, 200);
}
```

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY6Vi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all()` method returns `Collection` of models and each model should have `department` relation.

When you are trying to return this:

```
return response()->json($sites->department, 200);
```

You are accessing `department` property on `Collection` instance.
Instead you should call it on each model of that collection.

Here you can try solutions, depending what you want to achieve

Solution 1: (recomended)

```
$sites = InspectionSite::with('department')->get();
return response()->json($sites, 200);
// result
[
  {
    ...
    department: ...
  }
  ...
]
```

Solution 2: (Returns only depertments, not `InspectionSite` properties)

```
$sites = InspectionSite::with('department')->get()
->map(function($s) { 
   return $s->department;
});
return response()->json($sites, 200);
// result
[
  {
    [department]
  }
  {
    [department]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your answer solve the problem. I have one question o understand it logic.
If Model called with find() method, then its giving relationship data on Collection but not on all()?

Comment: Because `find` methods return instance of single mode. You can test it with `dd($var)` or `dump($var)` methods, then see class name they are instanciating to.